# Gravitationl law and angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Why angular momentum of earth is conserved about sun whereas external force are acting on earth such as gravitational force by planet

Comment: Well, there are tiny tidal effects that change the angular momentum...

Answer (score 0):

it is approximately conserved since the mass of the sun is so big compared to the orbiting planets. try to calculate the force of the sun on the earth and the force of the other planets on the earth and you'll see how negligible the other planets will be compared to the sun.